# Validation Formula

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need help with a formula that will return true only when

```
( category <> "red" )

OR

( category = "red" AND EmployeeName - a people picker field - is not empty )
```

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer ?

=IF([Category]=”red”,IF([EmployeeName]=””,FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)